Fundamental group of this space is $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$
Consider $S^3$ as a topological group with the product in $\mathbb{H}$. Let $R_k$ be the set consisting of the $k$-th roots of unity in $\mathbb{C}$. Then $R_k$ is a subgroup of $S^3$. Consider $\sim$ the relation modulo $R_k$ given by $x\sim y\iff xy^{-1}\in R_k$.
Then it should be that $\pi_1(S^3/\sim)\cong R_k$. This is because the canonical projection $p:S^3\to X$ is a covering space (one of the reasons being that $R_k$ is discrete), and that $S^3$ is simply connected.
Does this work? How would it generalize?

If you applied the same group to $S^1,$ you'd also get a covering space, but $S^1/\sim$ is homeomorphoc to $S^1.$ Also, $\pi_1(S^3)=0,$ so I don't see your argument for getting $\pi_1(X)=\mathbb Z_k.$ What theorem are you applying?

By $\mathbb{Z}_k$ I meant $\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}$. I.e. $R_k$. I changed it in case it affects your answer.

You stil,haven't said what theorem makes $\pi_1(X/\sim)\cong\mathbb C_k.$

@ThomasAndrews None that I know of. But you can map $[\tau]$ to $e^{2i\pi/k}$ where $\tau$ is a loop that can be lifted to a path from $1$ to $e^{2i\pi/k}$.

@RobArthan well it's obvious that $R_k\subset \mathbb{H}$ is discrete.

@RobArthan $R_k$ has $k$ elements. It is roots of unity in $\mathbb{C}$, not $\mathbb{H}$.

@ThomasAndrews $S^1$ is not simply connected.

Basically I'd say that two liftings of the same path in $X=S^3/\sim$ are multiples of each other by a factor in $R_k$. Moreover, a path in $X$ is null-homotopic if and only if its lifting in $S^3$ is.

A generalization would be that if a group $G$ acts properly discontinously on a simply connected topological space $X$, then the map $X\to X/G$ is a covering, and $\pi_1(X/G) = G$. An example is when $X$ is a manifold and $G$ is finite and the action doesn't have fixed points

@freakish: Apologies about the discreteness of $R_k$. I misread the question. I think that Luca is correct that about the fundamental group of the quotient space.

If $G$ is a (topological) group, and $H\subseteq G$ a subgroup, then $H$ acts on $G$ via $(h,g)\mapsto gh^{-1}$. This action has the property that the quotient space $G/H$ (which you refer to in your question) and the orbit space coincide.
Therefore we can talk about $R_k$ acting on $S^3$ instead. You can easily verify that this action is free. And since $R_k$ is additionally finite, then it satisfies Hatcher's (*) property (i.e. every point has a neighbourhood $U$ such that $g_1U\cap g_2U\neq\emptyset$ implies $g_1=g_2$). Therefore the quotient map $p:S^3\to X$ indeed is a covering map, by Proposition 1.40. in Allen Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology". By the same proposition $\pi_1(X)$ is isomorphic to $R_k$, precisely because $S^3$ is simply connected.
In this context Hatcher's Proposition 1.40. does sound like a good generalization:

Proposition 1.40. If an action of a group $G$ on a space $Y$ satisfies (*), then:
(a) The quotient map $p:Y\to Y/G$ is a normal covering;
(b) if $Y$ is path connected, then $G$ is the group of deck transformations of this covering;
(c) if $Y$ is path connected and locally path connected, then $G$ is isomorphic to $\pi_1(Y/G)/p_*(\pi_1(Y))$.

In particular (c) implies that if $Y$ is additionally simply connected, then $G$ is isomorphic to $\pi_1(Y/G)$.
